# wget returns 200/OK while org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient returns 404/NOT_FOUND

Tags: java, http-status-code-404, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to read this URL (  "https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF784GFP/@@download/ENCFF784GFP.hic" ) using http-components/java.

It works fine with wget:

```
wget -S -q -O - "https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF784GFP/@@download/ENCFF784GFP.hic" > /dev/null 
(...)
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  x-amz-id-2: 5vWTJmx5PF0uyuR8cUWwtx9zOei2ewX+yskiLlqKMFJOzkBKP/ND3pTKdC2/9+WYjqTIGuQ/Cp4=
  x-amz-request-id: B447183CF808894B
  Date: Fri, 14 Jun 2019 12:29:39 GMT
  Last-Modified: Sat, 09 Feb 2019 09:14:26 GMT
  ETag: "ccaabdcb885389d618bfe826e67fe680-521"
  Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ENCFF784GFP.hic
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
  Content-Length: 4367743691
  Server: AmazonS3
(...)
```

while I get a 404 with the following java code:

```
(...)
        final HttpClientBuilder hb = HttpClients.custom();
        final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = hb.build();

        final HttpHead httpHead = new HttpHead(url.toExternalForm());


            final CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpHead);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK ) {

                final String msg = "Unexpected Http status code "
                        + response.getStatusLine()+" for \""+ url+"\""
                        ;
                response.close();
                httpClient.close();
                throw new IOException(msg);
                }
(...)
```

with the following log:

```
2019/06/14 14:46:47:780 CEST [DEBUG] RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: default
2019/06/14 14:46:47:794 CEST [DEBUG] RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
2019/06/14 14:46:47:796 CEST [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://www.encodeproject.org:443][total kept alive: 0; rou
te allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
2019/06/14 14:46:47:814 CEST [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://www.encodeproject.org:443][total kept alive: 
0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
2019/06/14 14:46:47:815 CEST [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}->https://www.encodeproject.org:443
2019/06/14 14:46:47:844 CEST [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to www.encodeproject.org/34.211.244.144:443
2019/06/14 14:46:47:845 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Connecting socket to www.encodeproject.org/34.211.244.144:443 with timeout 0
2019/06/14 14:46:48:082 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
2019/06/14 14:46:48:082 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA38
4, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WIT
H_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS
_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_12
8_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_
DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_C
BC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDS
A_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_G
CM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_
ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION
_INFO_SCSV]
2019/06/14 14:46:48:082 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Starting handshake
2019/06/14 14:46:48:500 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Secure session established
2019/06/14 14:46:48:500 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
2019/06/14 14:46:48:501 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
2019/06/14 14:46:48:502 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer principal: CN=*.encodeproject.org, OU=Domain Control Validated
2019/06/14 14:46:48:503 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer alternative names: [*.encodeproject.org, encodeproject.org]
2019/06/14 14:46:48:503 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  issuer principal: CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
2019/06/14 14:46:48:507 CEST [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 172.18.240.255:59598<->34.211.244.144:443
2019/06/14 14:46:48:508 CEST [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Executing request HEAD /files/ENCFF784GFP/@@download/ENCFF784GFP.hic HTTP/1.1
2019/06/14 14:46:48:508 CEST [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2019/06/14 14:46:48:509 CEST [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2019/06/14 14:46:48:510 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 >> HEAD /files/ENCFF784GFP/@@download/ENCFF784GFP.hic HTTP/1.1
2019/06/14 14:46:48:510 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: www.encodeproject.org
2019/06/14 14:46:48:510 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2019/06/14 14:46:48:511 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5 (Java/1.8.0_191)
2019/06/14 14:46:48:511 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
2019/06/14 14:46:48:688 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
2019/06/14 14:46:48:689 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << Server: nginx/1.14.1
2019/06/14 14:46:48:689 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Fri, 14 Jun 2019 12:31:57 GMT
2019/06/14 14:46:48:689 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
2019/06/14 14:46:48:689 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 1569
2019/06/14 14:46:48:689 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << Connection: keep-alive
2019/06/14 14:46:48:689 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << X-Request-URL: https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF784GFP/@@download/ENCFF784GFP.hic
2019/06/14 14:46:48:689 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << X-Stats: es_count=1&es_time=1918&queue_begin=1560515517514062&queue_time=398&rss_begin=398917632&rss
_change=0&rss_end=398917632&wsgi_begin=1560515517514460&wsgi_end=1560515517522664&wsgi_time=8204
2019/06/14 14:46:48:689 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
2019/06/14 14:46:48:690 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD
2019/06/14 14:46:48:690 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Origin, Range, X-Requested-With
2019/06/14 14:46:48:690 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length, Content-Range, Content-Type
2019/06/14 14:46:48:690 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << Location: https://download.encodeproject.org/https://encode-public.s3.amazonaws.com/2018/04/06/8723e
e96-ccee-4384-b5a8-4040262283eb/ENCFF784GFP.hic?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DENCFF784GFP.hic&Signature=YZmRQyN1SPT0vpRjyscTzLgV3WM%3D&x-amz
-security-token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEMT%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIBECuWysenOZdkDKbB6XfmcaQ8zul6azEkuNauJcIB91AiEA6%2FLuT9kpu%2BIvggBn3Dp7mJBxg9
2zGio1NlitzdjrJ08q4wMI7f%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAAGgwyMjA3NDg3MTQ4NjMiDCYx83zFw7htd3syviq3AzISSluwceByIAxIcFaxcorsp2pKt8ZqsPUcgjsIeWJR2CaHnhyxGLXV3ydF8C4CmxYY
bgepXvPKTYy6i0UASGK8YJf2mPlzGoXjdiRZo%2BpjTJmhVO59CYgV%2B%2BoJqHYOkYqEotyfNT%2BOYxaMum0qzeOfpWjrApXqNyrBkkrowu6Ng85eDNjmZTO0DZWGJICZm%2FiBEi%2B6sewE3aGBLdTGiaKhmbDsKj
uNUNcBUwZfYfjBt0OwAASJZrC6C%2BjVSfiLjgBOaeY8pXqKmZ1X218AjX6vVzCSnriYvsLY1fmgCdu66ifTUU5GL5NqyDmS76UVO1PoviFSctLBU%2B%2BJtQBWwk%2BcoLS0oIU1%2FhtnoHYKH4M%2B2ne3z1w5i86L
1zsdUMXqZQ8AZ1A03iCUhQzCnDo%2Bo04njmhlF08voTZKVHbZ2icSEiKYERboR%2BMIhicYDtDhkRCcTZooP55A%2FSD9Ov4YtkwmpRgoBRMCYkiNl4rLD6MNyGipFJdFeoHllVZCfbMSjtOwmZRcOdKzZuJ%2FCDZhgP
njbzGc0oe%2Fp0QpXfYHNN00g6XEQdleW%2BcSGIDx7hMzuZydGxWOf7IwlpuO6AU6tAF4294kivKpwT90N%2FCA%2Fdquas6GmSMLpRWET%2FGcjgu9mhHXH0cZ3OOFHmWs%2Bo4e5o2i7geA7yCALBw4aIf%2BPpRUjR
EIx9IOPzMJHtKqDX8BLgFnjrvR2FXeiCnW%2BN0YxXGDP%2BRrlxLDkxBVbH6afcfV7ysqHIAwkWTUNlz7wKkCy4aIAfB3mPqMp3WsJ5KDx7xSNDfVe1kvsmNv8%2FIWed1K3KlnjG5VVbH2IklxMBJw5%2FYqSaQ%3D&E
xpires=1560645117&AWSAccessKeyId=ASIATGZNGCNXXYADQSVU
2019/06/14 14:46:48:690 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-0 << Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
2019/06/14 14:46:48:694 CEST [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2019/06/14 14:46:48:695 CEST [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection [id: 0][route: {s}->https://www.encodeproject.org:443] can be kept alive indefini
tely
2019/06/14 14:46:48:695 CEST [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://www.encodeproject.org:443][total kept alive
: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
2019/06/14 14:46:48:698 CEST [DEBUG] DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirect requested to location 'https://download.encodeproject.org/https://encode-public.s3.amazonaws.c
om/2018/04/06/8723ee96-ccee-4384-b5a8-4040262283eb/ENCFF784GFP.hic?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DENCFF784GFP.hic&Signature=YZmRQyN1SPT0vpRjy
scTzLgV3WM%3D&x-amz-security-token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEMT%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIBECuWysenOZdkDKbB6XfmcaQ8zul6azEkuNauJcIB91AiEA6%2FLuT9kpu
%2BIvggBn3Dp7mJBxg92zGio1NlitzdjrJ08q4wMI7f%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAAGgwyMjA3NDg3MTQ4NjMiDCYx83zFw7htd3syviq3AzISSluwceByIAxIcFaxcorsp2pKt8ZqsPUcgjsIeWJR2CaHn
hyxGLXV3ydF8C4CmxYYbgepXvPKTYy6i0UASGK8YJf2mPlzGoXjdiRZo%2BpjTJmhVO59CYgV%2B%2BoJqHYOkYqEotyfNT%2BOYxaMum0qzeOfpWjrApXqNyrBkkrowu6Ng85eDNjmZTO0DZWGJICZm%2FiBEi%2B6sew
E3aGBLdTGiaKhmbDsKjuNUNcBUwZfYfjBt0OwAASJZrC6C%2BjVSfiLjgBOaeY8pXqKmZ1X218AjX6vVzCSnriYvsLY1fmgCdu66ifTUU5GL5NqyDmS76UVO1PoviFSctLBU%2B%2BJtQBWwk%2BcoLS0oIU1%2FhtnoHY
KH4M%2B2ne3z1w5i86L1zsdUMXqZQ8AZ1A03iCUhQzCnDo%2Bo04njmhlF08voTZKVHbZ2icSEiKYERboR%2BMIhicYDtDhkRCcTZooP55A%2FSD9Ov4YtkwmpRgoBRMCYkiNl4rLD6MNyGipFJdFeoHllVZCfbMSjtOwm
ZRcOdKzZuJ%2FCDZhgPnjbzGc0oe%2Fp0QpXfYHNN00g6XEQdleW%2BcSGIDx7hMzuZydGxWOf7IwlpuO6AU6tAF4294kivKpwT90N%2FCA%2Fdquas6GmSMLpRWET%2FGcjgu9mhHXH0cZ3OOFHmWs%2Bo4e5o2i7geA7
yCALBw4aIf%2BPpRUjREIx9IOPzMJHtKqDX8BLgFnjrvR2FXeiCnW%2BN0YxXGDP%2BRrlxLDkxBVbH6afcfV7ysqHIAwkWTUNlz7wKkCy4aIAfB3mPqMp3WsJ5KDx7xSNDfVe1kvsmNv8%2FIWed1K3KlnjG5VVbH2Ikl
xMBJw5%2FYqSaQ%3D&Expires=1560645117&AWSAccessKeyId=ASIATGZNGCNXXYADQSVU'
2019/06/14 14:46:48:707 CEST [DEBUG] RedirectExec - Resetting target auth state
2019/06/14 14:46:48:708 CEST [DEBUG] RedirectExec - Redirecting to 'https://download.encodeproject.org/https:/encode-public.s3.amazonaws.com/2018/04/06/8723ee96-ccee-
4384-b5a8-4040262283eb/ENCFF784GFP.hic?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DENCFF784GFP.hic&Signature=YZmRQyN1SPT0vpRjyscTzLgV3WM%3D&x-amz-security
-token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEMT%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIBECuWysenOZdkDKbB6XfmcaQ8zul6azEkuNauJcIB91AiEA6%2FLuT9kpu%2BIvggBn3Dp7mJBxg92zGio1Nli
tzdjrJ08q4wMI7f%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAAGgwyMjA3NDg3MTQ4NjMiDCYx83zFw7htd3syviq3AzISSluwceByIAxIcFaxcorsp2pKt8ZqsPUcgjsIeWJR2CaHnhyxGLXV3ydF8C4CmxYYbgepXvPKT
Yy6i0UASGK8YJf2mPlzGoXjdiRZo%2BpjTJmhVO59CYgV%2B%2BoJqHYOkYqEotyfNT%2BOYxaMum0qzeOfpWjrApXqNyrBkkrowu6Ng85eDNjmZTO0DZWGJICZm%2FiBEi%2B6sewE3aGBLdTGiaKhmbDsKjuNUNcBUwZ
fYfjBt0OwAASJZrC6C%2BjVSfiLjgBOaeY8pXqKmZ1X218AjX6vVzCSnriYvsLY1fmgCdu66ifTUU5GL5NqyDmS76UVO1PoviFSctLBU%2B%2BJtQBWwk%2BcoLS0oIU1%2FhtnoHYKH4M%2B2ne3z1w5i86L1zsdUMXqZ
Q8AZ1A03iCUhQzCnDo%2Bo04njmhlF08voTZKVHbZ2icSEiKYERboR%2BMIhicYDtDhkRCcTZooP55A%2FSD9Ov4YtkwmpRgoBRMCYkiNl4rLD6MNyGipFJdFeoHllVZCfbMSjtOwmZRcOdKzZuJ%2FCDZhgPnjbzGc0oe
%2Fp0QpXfYHNN00g6XEQdleW%2BcSGIDx7hMzuZydGxWOf7IwlpuO6AU6tAF4294kivKpwT90N%2FCA%2Fdquas6GmSMLpRWET%2FGcjgu9mhHXH0cZ3OOFHmWs%2Bo4e5o2i7geA7yCALBw4aIf%2BPpRUjREIx9IOPzM
JHtKqDX8BLgFnjrvR2FXeiCnW%2BN0YxXGDP%2BRrlxLDkxBVbH6afcfV7ysqHIAwkWTUNlz7wKkCy4aIAfB3mPqMp3WsJ5KDx7xSNDfVe1kvsmNv8%2FIWed1K3KlnjG5VVbH2IklxMBJw5%2FYqSaQ%3D&Expires=15
60645117&AWSAccessKeyId=ASIATGZNGCNXXYADQSVU' via {s}->https://download.encodeproject.org:443
2019/06/14 14:46:48:710 CEST [DEBUG] RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: default
2019/06/14 14:46:48:710 CEST [DEBUG] RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
2019/06/14 14:46:48:710 CEST [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://download.encodeproject.org:443][total kept alive: 1
; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
2019/06/14 14:46:48:711 CEST [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 1][route: {s}->https://download.encodeproject.org:443][total kept al
ive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 20]
2019/06/14 14:46:48:711 CEST [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}->https://download.encodeproject.org:443
2019/06/14 14:46:48:890 CEST [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to download.encodeproject.org/34.211.244.144:443
2019/06/14 14:46:48:891 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Connecting socket to download.encodeproject.org/34.211.244.144:443 with timeout 0
2019/06/14 14:46:49:048 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
2019/06/14 14:46:49:048 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA38
4, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WIT
H_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS
_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_12
8_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_
DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_C
BC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDS
A_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_G
CM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_
ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION
_INFO_SCSV]
2019/06/14 14:46:49:048 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Starting handshake
2019/06/14 14:46:49:388 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Secure session established
2019/06/14 14:46:49:388 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
2019/06/14 14:46:49:388 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
2019/06/14 14:46:49:388 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer principal: CN=*.encodeproject.org, OU=Domain Control Validated
2019/06/14 14:46:49:388 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer alternative names: [*.encodeproject.org, encodeproject.org]
2019/06/14 14:46:49:388 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  issuer principal: CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
2019/06/14 14:46:49:389 CEST [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 172.18.240.255:59602<->34.211.244.144:443
2019/06/14 14:46:49:389 CEST [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Executing request HEAD /https:/encode-public.s3.amazonaws.com/2018/04/06/8723ee96-ccee-4384-b5a8-4040262283eb/EN
CFF784GFP.hic?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DENCFF784GFP.hic&Signature=YZmRQyN1SPT0vpRjyscTzLgV3WM%3D&x-amz-security-token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEM
T%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIBECuWysenOZdkDKbB6XfmcaQ8zul6azEkuNauJcIB91AiEA6%2FLuT9kpu%2BIvggBn3Dp7mJBxg92zGio1NlitzdjrJ08q4wMI7f%2F%2F%2F%
2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAAGgwyMjA3NDg3MTQ4NjMiDCYx83zFw7htd3syviq3AzISSluwceByIAxIcFaxcorsp2pKt8ZqsPUcgjsIeWJR2CaHnhyxGLXV3ydF8C4CmxYYbgepXvPKTYy6i0UASGK8YJf2mPlzGoXjdi
RZo%2BpjTJmhVO59CYgV%2B%2BoJqHYOkYqEotyfNT%2BOYxaMum0qzeOfpWjrApXqNyrBkkrowu6Ng85eDNjmZTO0DZWGJICZm%2FiBEi%2B6sewE3aGBLdTGiaKhmbDsKjuNUNcBUwZfYfjBt0OwAASJZrC6C%2BjVSf
iLjgBOaeY8pXqKmZ1X218AjX6vVzCSnriYvsLY1fmgCdu66ifTUU5GL5NqyDmS76UVO1PoviFSctLBU%2B%2BJtQBWwk%2BcoLS0oIU1%2FhtnoHYKH4M%2B2ne3z1w5i86L1zsdUMXqZQ8AZ1A03iCUhQzCnDo%2Bo04n
jmhlF08voTZKVHbZ2icSEiKYERboR%2BMIhicYDtDhkRCcTZooP55A%2FSD9Ov4YtkwmpRgoBRMCYkiNl4rLD6MNyGipFJdFeoHllVZCfbMSjtOwmZRcOdKzZuJ%2FCDZhgPnjbzGc0oe%2Fp0QpXfYHNN00g6XEQdleW%
2BcSGIDx7hMzuZydGxWOf7IwlpuO6AU6tAF4294kivKpwT90N%2FCA%2Fdquas6GmSMLpRWET%2FGcjgu9mhHXH0cZ3OOFHmWs%2Bo4e5o2i7geA7yCALBw4aIf%2BPpRUjREIx9IOPzMJHtKqDX8BLgFnjrvR2FXeiCnW
%2BN0YxXGDP%2BRrlxLDkxBVbH6afcfV7ysqHIAwkWTUNlz7wKkCy4aIAfB3mPqMp3WsJ5KDx7xSNDfVe1kvsmNv8%2FIWed1K3KlnjG5VVbH2IklxMBJw5%2FYqSaQ%3D&Expires=1560645117&AWSAccessKeyId=A
SIATGZNGCNXXYADQSVU HTTP/1.1
2019/06/14 14:46:49:389 CEST [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2019/06/14 14:46:49:389 CEST [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2019/06/14 14:46:49:390 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> HEAD /https:/encode-public.s3.amazonaws.com/2018/04/06/8723ee96-ccee-4384-b5a8-4040262283eb/ENCFF784
GFP.hic?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DENCFF784GFP.hic&Signature=YZmRQyN1SPT0vpRjyscTzLgV3WM%3D&x-amz-security-token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEMT%2F%2
F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIBECuWysenOZdkDKbB6XfmcaQ8zul6azEkuNauJcIB91AiEA6%2FLuT9kpu%2BIvggBn3Dp7mJBxg92zGio1NlitzdjrJ08q4wMI7f%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%
2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAAGgwyMjA3NDg3MTQ4NjMiDCYx83zFw7htd3syviq3AzISSluwceByIAxIcFaxcorsp2pKt8ZqsPUcgjsIeWJR2CaHnhyxGLXV3ydF8C4CmxYYbgepXvPKTYy6i0UASGK8YJf2mPlzGoXjdiRZo%2B
pjTJmhVO59CYgV%2B%2BoJqHYOkYqEotyfNT%2BOYxaMum0qzeOfpWjrApXqNyrBkkrowu6Ng85eDNjmZTO0DZWGJICZm%2FiBEi%2B6sewE3aGBLdTGiaKhmbDsKjuNUNcBUwZfYfjBt0OwAASJZrC6C%2BjVSfiLjgBO
aeY8pXqKmZ1X218AjX6vVzCSnriYvsLY1fmgCdu66ifTUU5GL5NqyDmS76UVO1PoviFSctLBU%2B%2BJtQBWwk%2BcoLS0oIU1%2FhtnoHYKH4M%2B2ne3z1w5i86L1zsdUMXqZQ8AZ1A03iCUhQzCnDo%2Bo04njmhlF0
8voTZKVHbZ2icSEiKYERboR%2BMIhicYDtDhkRCcTZooP55A%2FSD9Ov4YtkwmpRgoBRMCYkiNl4rLD6MNyGipFJdFeoHllVZCfbMSjtOwmZRcOdKzZuJ%2FCDZhgPnjbzGc0oe%2Fp0QpXfYHNN00g6XEQdleW%2BcSGI
Dx7hMzuZydGxWOf7IwlpuO6AU6tAF4294kivKpwT90N%2FCA%2Fdquas6GmSMLpRWET%2FGcjgu9mhHXH0cZ3OOFHmWs%2Bo4e5o2i7geA7yCALBw4aIf%2BPpRUjREIx9IOPzMJHtKqDX8BLgFnjrvR2FXeiCnW%2BN0Y
xXGDP%2BRrlxLDkxBVbH6afcfV7ysqHIAwkWTUNlz7wKkCy4aIAfB3mPqMp3WsJ5KDx7xSNDfVe1kvsmNv8%2FIWed1K3KlnjG5VVbH2IklxMBJw5%2FYqSaQ%3D&Expires=1560645117&AWSAccessKeyId=ASIATGZ
NGCNXXYADQSVU HTTP/1.1
2019/06/14 14:46:49:390 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Host: download.encodeproject.org
2019/06/14 14:46:49:390 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2019/06/14 14:46:49:390 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5 (Java/1.8.0_191)
2019/06/14 14:46:49:392 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
2019/06/14 14:46:49:548 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
2019/06/14 14:46:49:548 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << Server: nginx/1.14.1
2019/06/14 14:46:49:548 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << Date: Fri, 14 Jun 2019 12:31:58 GMT
2019/06/14 14:46:49:548 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << Content-Type: text/html
2019/06/14 14:46:49:548 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << Content-Length: 169
2019/06/14 14:46:49:548 CEST [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << Connection: keep-alive
2019/06/14 14:46:49:549 CEST [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2019/06/14 14:46:49:549 CEST [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection [id: 1][route: {s}->https://download.encodeproject.org:443] can be kept alive ind
efinitely
2019/06/14 14:46:49:549 CEST [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 1][route: {s}->https://download.encodeproject.org:443][total kept 
alive: 2; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 20]
2019/06/14 14:46:49:549 CEST [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection manager is shutting down
2019/06/14 14:46:49:549 CEST [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-1: Close connection
2019/06/14 14:46:49:550 CEST [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
2019/06/14 14:46:49:550 CEST [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
2019/06/14 14:46:49:551 CEST [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-1: Close connection
2019/06/14 14:46:49:551 CEST [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection manager shut down
[SEVERE][HicFileInfo]Unexpected Http status code HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found for "https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF784GFP/@@download/ENCFF784GFP.hic"
```

setting the user-agent doesn't work.

how can I fix this ? thanks

Comment: Did you check that the @ symbols are encoded properly? Also, you are doing a HEAD request in your Java code (just telling you in case that leads to problems later).

Comment: @biG-AdR Yes I'm doing a HEAD, I also tested with Get : same result

Comment: @biG-AdR I used '%40%40' instead of '%%'  , I got a 404 too

Comment: Looks like the lib is not understanding the redirect correctly. If you look at the log, you can see that it is redirecting you to https://download.encodeproject.org/https:/encode-public.s3.amazonaws.com/2018/04/06/8723ee96-ccee-
4384-b5a8-4040262283eb/ENCFF784GFP.hic?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DENCFF784GFP.hic&Signature=YZmRQyN1SPT0vpRjyscTzLgV3WM%3D&x-amz-security
-token=<LONG TOKEN>

Comment: There is one / missing at the second https (after download.encodeproject.org/https:/). If I enter the exact same URL from the log, I also get a 404 in Chrome. Adding an additional / solves this.

Comment: @biG-AdR thanks, but Unless I'm wrong copying+pasting the url into wget works too (200/OK).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I posted my question at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1993?

I'm citing here Oleg Kalnichevski's answer.

> The redirect URI returned by the server contains unescaped reserved
>   characters in the path component.

https://download.encodeproject.org/https://encode-public.s3.amazonaws.com/2018/04/06/8723ee96-ccee-4384-b5a8-4040262283eb/ENCFF784GFP.hic

> If you want HttpClient to pass that sequence onto the server without
>   validating and normalizing it, you can disable request URI
>   normalization with RequestConfig .

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createSystem();
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setNormalizeUri(false).build();
HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.create();
clientContext.setRequestConfig(requestConfig);
try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(
        new HttpGet("https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF784GFP/@@download/ENCFF784GFP.hic"),
        clientContext)) {
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    EntityUtils.consume(entity);
}

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: HttpClient committer here, request your faulty to be fixed.

Comment: @Michael-O It's not a bug in httpClient, just a misconfiguration on my side, so I don't understand the sentence "request your faulty to be fixed"

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to be URL provider.

Comment: Note to self: amazon doesn't like 'HttpHead'